# Copying (Ctrl-C) shapes in Excel VBA inherits old position values

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I'm trying to copy a shape from one cell to another (as new rows are created, so no overriding need for a separate macro to do this).

When I do so using Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V and then try to run the following macro...

```
Dim b As Object, rn As Integer, cn As Integer
Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
With b.TopLeftCell
    rn = .Row
    cn = .Column
End With
*then other stuff to manipulate that cell
```

...the new shape winds up with the same .Row and .Column values as the old shape, i.e. the shape it was copied from, and thus winds up controlling THAT cell and not the one that it's actually in. Any ideas on how I can get the new shape to find the .Row and .Column of the cell it's actually in?

Comment: Does the pasted shape have a unique name?

Comment: It doesn't. I changed the shape name and it now works as it should...but I wasn't referencing shape names in my macro to begin with, so why does it look at shape name rather than simply the local variable b to derive .Row and .Column?

Comment: `Application.Caller` is the name of the shape - it gets passed to your macro when it's called by the `OnAction` ...  So if there are >1 shape with the same name that will cause problems since there's no guarantee you get the correct one when you call `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)`

Answer (score 0):

If your copied shape doesn't have a unique name then your code will have problems.

`Application.Caller` is the name of the clicked-on shape - it gets passed to your macro when it's called by the shape's `OnAction` property.

So if there are >1 shape with the same name that will cause problems, as there's no guarantee you get the correct one when you call ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)